# Pytorch-size mismatch when loading the pretrained model

Tags: python, pytorch

Could someone help me with this issue as I am unable to get this right.

I want to load my pretrained models for reinforcement learning. That's how I save and load the model:

```
def save(self, folder_to_save='./'):
    if folder_to_save[-1] != '/':
        folder_to_save = folder_to_save + '/'
    torch.save(self.enc.state_dict(), folder_to_save + 'enc.model')
    torch.save(self.dec.state_dict(), folder_to_save + 'dec.model')
    torch.save(self.lp.state_dict(), folder_to_save + 'lp.model')

    pickle.dump(self.lp.order, open(folder_to_save + 'order.pkl', 'wb'))

def load(self, folder_to_load='./'):
    if folder_to_load[-1] != '/':
        folder_to_load = folder_to_load + '/'

    order = pickle.load(open(folder_to_load + 'order.pkl', 'rb'))
    self.lp = LP(distr_descr=self.latent_descr + self.feature_descr,
                 tt_int=self.tt_int, tt_type=self.tt_type,
                 order=order)

    self.enc.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_to_load + 'enc.model'))
    self.dec.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_to_load + 'dec.model'))
    self.lp.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_to_load + 'lp.model'))
```

and in .ipynb files I use:

```
model.save('./saved_gentrl/')
enc = gentrl.RNNEncoder(latent_size=50)
dec = gentrl.DilConvDecoder(latent_input_size=50)
model = gentrl.GENTRL(enc, dec, 50 * [('c', 20)], [('c', 20)], beta=0.001)
model.cuda();
model.load('saved_gentrl/')
model.cuda();
```

But the error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for RNNEncoder:size mismatch for embs.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([28, 256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([31, 256]).
```

The traceback is:

```
/Colab Notebooks/GENTRL-master/gentrl/gentrl.py in load(self, folder_to_load)
114                      order=order)
115 
116         self.enc.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_to_load + 'enc.model'))
117         self.dec.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_to_load + 'dec.model'))
118         self.lp.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_to_load + 'lp.model'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)

1050         load = None  # break load->load reference cycle
1052         return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)
1053 
1054     def _named_members(self, get_members_fn, prefix='', recurse=True):
```

I guess this may because I added 3 more features in token list, which lead vocab_size change from 28 to 31, but this parameter only use as：

```
self.embs = nn.Embedding(get_vocab_size(), hidden_size)
self.vocab_size = get_vocab_size()
```

I can not figure out why, please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: *"I guess this may because I added 3 more features in token list, which lead `vocab_size` change from 28 to 31 [...]"* nailed it, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: @Ivan But I don't know how to avoid this error. The checkpoint shows 28, but the code def get_vocab_size():  return len(__i2t) doesn't equal to 28.